# My TextView to display an array isn't working?

Tags: java, android, arrays, methods

In my app I have a method that is designed to put a new string into a string array in the first empty index. It is then designed to display that array in a textbox that has ten lines. For some reason, this is not working. I have used a Log to display the array contents in Logcat, but this is not appearing. So I thought I'd come here and ask if anyone can see any obvious errors that would cause it not to work? If you need any more details, such as the class from which the array is used, let me know! :)

The method:

```
     String playerInvTemp[] = thePlayer.getPlayerInv();
               for (int i=0; i < playerInvTemp.length; i++)
               {
                   if ((!playerInvTemp[i].isEmpty()) || playerInvTemp[i] == null)
                   {
                       thePlayer.setPlayerInv("Torch", i);
                       Log.i(tag,thePlayer.getPlayerInv(1));
                       playerInvTemp = thePlayer.getPlayerInv();
                       Log.i(tag,playerInvTemp[1]);


                       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                       for (String s : playerInvTemp) {
                           builder.append(s + " ");
                           invText.setText(builder.toString());
                       }

                       break;
                   }
               }
```

Comment: By "empty index", you mean "empty item".

Comment: you have to step through with a debugger and see whats up, what I'm thinking since you said that the Logs aren't showing is that playerInvTemp.length is 0 and you for loop never iterates, maybe your thePlayer.getPlayerInv() isn't returning anything

Comment: It might not be. At this point in the program it should just be ten empty strings, but that would still return as {"","","" etc.} would it not?

Comment: this is the problem (for (int i=0; i < playerInvTemp.length; i++)) if your array is empty in the 1st place the its not going to do any work

Comment: Your method dosplays the joined array (why not simply using `join()`?) only if an empty item is found. And id keeps doing that for every empty items found.

Comment: I see... So if when I create the array I filled it with "Nothing" for instance and changed the check for ifArray[i].equals("Nothing") that might solve it?

Comment: Why not simply `if Array[i].equals("")`?

Comment: put @ and then the name of he person you are directing the comment e.g @somePerson i see...

Comment: Tried .equals("") and it still does nothing.

Comment: @Tasos Sorry dude, when I replied to your comment my feed hadn't updated haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is a very bad practice to change the array you are iterating on inside loop.
2. Probably, you have an array of empty strings, in that case you condition:

   ((!playerInvTemp[i].isEmpty()) || playerInvTemp[i] == null)

remains false. Maybe you meant:

```
(!(playerInvTemp[i].isEmpty() || playerInvTemp[i] == null))
```

Comment: Yeah, I changed the array so that it's filled with "Empty" instead of "" when it's created. However, it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Have you changed the condition as I proposed?

Comment: I have. Still no change.

Comment: Than add this code right after definition of playerInvTemp: `for (int i=0; i < playerInvTemp.length; i++)
 playerInvTemp[i] = "a";` Your problem is that your array values are empty and you never enter your if condition.